# Do cyclones or hurricanes form near the equator?

Tags: weather, meteorology

I'm a pretty intelligent guy (I like to think) and I work with a pretty intelligent guy. Today, I said cyclones can't *form* close to the equator, thinking cyclones need the Coriolis effect. He was quite adament that they could and sent me [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Storm_Vamei):

> (Tropical Cyclone) Vamei formed and reached tropical storm strength at 1.5º N

But I came back with [this](http://www.smh.com.au/news/big-questions/if-a-hurricane-rotates-in-one-direction-and-a-cyclone-rotates-inthe-other-what-happens-if-they-cross-the-equator/2005/09/15/1126750065686.html):

> Hurricanes and cyclones can't actually *form* within 4 degrees of the equator, because the Coriolis effect is just too small

Do cyclones (or hurricanes) form within 4 degrees of the equator?

Comment: I've made a small, but significant change to your question: we can't really answer whether they theoretically can form there but only whether they practically do from there. If they do form there, then they certainly can - not so clear otherwise...

Comment: "I said cyclones can form" should probably be "I said cyclones cannot form"?

Comment: It seems the articles linked pretty much sum up the knowledge and show you are both right. Cyclones do not normally form near the equator, but rarely they do: "the probability for a similar equatorial development was at least once every four centuries."

Comment: Looking at the second article, it seems that the 4 degrees limitation assumes no nearby land to affect wind patterns.

Comment: Anyone reading back at this... the question [Impossible or improbable? Hurricane crossing the equator](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/239/impossible-or-improbable-hurricane-crossing-the-equator) at Earth Science SE should give very important insight on the topic too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Can* they form near the the equator?  Yes.  [Cyclone Agni](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cyclone_Agni) from 2004 is probably the best example of this: according to the India Meteorological Department, it was 1.5 degrees north of the equator when it became a tropical cyclone, and before it reached that strength, the circulation center may have crossed the equator twice.

*Is it normal?*  No.  There are any number of sources that will tell you that tropical cyclones normally form at least 5 degrees poleward of the equator (eg. [this NOAA page](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/Landsea/IPCC/) (warning: contains Geocities-style web design)); most of these trace back to work by [William Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_M._Gray), but the general situation can be summarized by the following image:

[image: Tropical Cyclone tracks from 1945 to 2006, showing a distinct gap at the equator]
Image by [Wikipedia user Citynoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tropical_cyclones_1945_2006_wikicolor.png) using NOAA data.